# RestTemplate for @RequestBody and @RequestParam

Tags: java, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I'm trying to use RestTemplate to call POST api like that :

```
RequestorParam  test = new RequestorParam();
test.setScopeMcg("MCG");
test.setSituatedDealIds(situatedDealIds);

String url = "http://localhost:" + serverPort + "/retrieveAttributes";
ResponseEntity<SituatedDeals> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, test, SituatedDeals.class);
```

and the code of the controller is like ;

```
  @PostMapping(value = "/retrieveAttributes", produces = "application/json")
  @ResponseBody
  @Duration
  public SituatedDeals retrieveAttributes(
        @RequestParam String scopeMcg, 
        @RequestBody SituatedDealIds situatedDealIds 
    ) {
        log.info("success")
  }
```

i'm getting bad request, can someone help ?

Comment: if you have a bad request error, what is the response body ?

Comment: i'm getting null object in the response, but when debugging i'm getting one the line of resttemplate.postForEntity a bad request message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. According to your controller code, you are actually not returning any Response Entity of type `SituatedDeals`, just logging it as success. this might be the reason for the `null` object in response.
2. The `scopeMcg` is a RequestParameter so you should be passing it in a request param format i.e `http://localhost:8080/retrieveAttributes?scopeMcg=MCG`
   Reference:[Spring Request Param](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-request-param)
3. Your `test` Object is the actual payload for your post request which should be of type SituatedDealIds object.
   Reference: [Rest-Template post for Entity](https://www.concretepage.com/spring-5/spring-resttemplate-postforentity)

Comment: Thank ou for your response, but i still getting the bad request, using restTemplate.postForEntity(url, situatedDealIds, SituatedDeals.class, scopeMcg) scopeMcg is String object

Comment: Could You Try this


`restTemplate.postForEntity(url, situatedDealIds, SituatedDeals.class);`
where url = `http://localhost:<your_port>/retrieveAttributes?scopeMcg=MCG`